# getting keys in a dictionary that do not contain "x" variable Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I have the following dictionary

dictionary = {'\x85': 1, '\x84': 1, 'C': 3828}

What I want is only the keys and corresponding values for keys that don't contain digits, this is what I wrote but it's not working. I'm getting a key error. I import re at the top by the way.

```
new_dictionary = {}   
for key in diciontary:  
      if r"\d" not in key:  
              new_dictionary[key] += dictionary[key]
```

this isn't working however, i'm getting a key error. Which I think means that key doesn't exist, but that's exactly what I want, everything but the keys with digits.

My expected output in this case is
dictionary = {'C': 3828}

Although I think I may be having troubles because the key is a string and even though there is a digit in it i think it's read a string, so the regex wouldn't work here?

This is actually a part of a huge dictionary, and this code I have pasted here worked for other instances in which there was a digit, however there were some that came through? Is that because the acutal characters were saved as different types? Either way, I'm not sure how to remove them.

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: `'\x85'` contains no digits. You're most likely going about this the wrong way. Why does your dict have these keys in it in the first place, and what property of these keys makes you want them gone?

Comment: I only want digits, not meaning that I want x from this key value. If it contains anything besides letters I want to exclude the entire key. I tried referring to them with "\\" but that wasn't working as well?

Comment: ***hint***:  what is your expected output for the `dictionary = {'\x43': 3828}` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use regex pattern inside search or match function. So change the if condition to,

```
if not re.search(r"\d", key):
```

OR

```
>>> dictionary = {'\x85': 1, '\x84': 1, 'C': 3828}
>>> {i:j for i,j in dictionary.items() if re.search(r'[A-Za-z]', i)}
{'C': 3828}
```

This would print the dictionary item if there is a single letter found on the key.

Comment: it's not printing out a key error message, but it still prints the values that contain digits, I think this is because the entire key is a string. I think that can happen in python correct?

Comment: note that `'\x85'` prints out a unicode character. So the above regex pattern will also print the value of `'\x85'` key.

Comment: ya, that's not what I want. I made an edit in the original text, take a look

Answer (score 3):

```
new_dictionary = {k:v for k,v in dictionary.iteritems() if k.isalpha()}
```

Comment: Nobody likes a smart alec :-)

Comment: This might not do what the OP wants if there are keys like `'.'` or `'}'` in the dict.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be confused about what those strings like `'\x85'` actually are.  These are not necessarily strings with digits in them.  They are [escape sequences](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-literals).

```
\xhh    Character with hex value hh
```

Nobody can tell you how to strip them out unless you more clearly identify what is the problem with them, and what characters you want remaining in the output.

For example, `'\x43'`  is another way of representing the string 'C' in python, so the following two dicts are actually equal!

```
>>> dict1 = {'\x85': 1, '\x84': 1, 'C': 3828}
>>> dict2 = {'\x85': 1, '\x84': 1, '\x43': 3828}
>>> dict1 == dict2
True
```